# Using Grunt-Contrib-Watch with asp.net-vnext and Visual Studio 15

Tags: grunt-contrib-watch, asp.net-core

I have been playing around with asp.net-vnext, and am currently looking at the grunt integration using the task runner in Visual Studio 2015,

I have a grunt file that uses grunt-contrib-watch to monitor my SASS files and compile them into CSS in WWWRoot  whenever they are .

The grunt file works, but when I attach it to the post-build event, and debugging, VS doesn't launch a browser.  I think this is because the grunt-contrib-watch task never returns, so VS can't tell the task is complete.

I could use a grunt-concurrent and grunt-open task to open the browser while the watch task is running but that would mean hardcoding the project url into the grunt file, not keen on that, it feels a bit hacky.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks

Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is not the way it's intended to be used, and as has been pointed out to me, watching files for changes, is not really related to build anyway.

I added another task to the GruntFile which just watches SCSS files and have associated it to the project open event in TaskRunner instead.  Seems to work perfectly.